# Не срабатывает onSaveInstanсeState

Tags: java, android, activity-life-cycle

У меня есть активность с двумя методами (для сохранения и возобновления переменной):

```
public class DataActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>> {
    ...
    ...
    ...

    private final static String KEY_IS_LOAD_FINISHED = "LOAD_FINISHED";
    private boolean isLoadFinished = false;

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
        outState.putBoolean(KEY_IS_LOAD_FINISHED, isLoadFinished);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        isLoadFinished = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_IS_LOAD_FINISHED);
    }

    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Проблема в том, что `onRestoreInstaceState` вызывается, а `онSaveInstanceState` — нет. Смотрел по логам. Но почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы какой-то неправильный `onSaveInstanceState` используете. В оригинале сигнатура нужного вам метода не имеет второго аргумента и выглядит вот так:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    ...
}
```

Используемый же вами метод предназначен для восстановления данных активити после перезагрузки девайса. И требует дополнительного аттрибута при создании активити. См. доки на сей счёт: [тык](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.PersistableBundle))

Comment: Фух, я уже испугался, что Вы спать пошли. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: @bukashka101, тут и пробовать не надо и так всё ясно) И вам повезло, что я засыпаю в обнимку с ноутом)))

Comment: Подождите засыпать... Я тут `onActivityResult` пытаюсь получить в фрагмент... Не совсем успешно.

Comment: Ой... Я не при том нажатии вызываю. Я тормоз :\. Заработало.

Comment: @bukashka101, уверен, что если вы этим будете при свете дня заниматься, то внимательность повысится)

Comment: Завтра проекты satnov'у дам посмотреть. Обещал помочь исправить ошибку с тормозами при изменении текста (я ее все-таки не решил), да и в общем просмотреть код, поправить, грубо говоря — наставить на пусть истинный. Завтра уезжаю, нужно успеть, так что нужно его хорошенько отрефакторить. У меня с рефакторингом и так записки сумасшедшего, а без него...